# derivative $f(z)=\sqrt [n] {g(z)}$ and $f(z)=\log(g(z))$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives, logarithms, roots

How I can compute the derivative at a point of function $f(z)=\sqrt [n] {g(z)}$ and $f(z)=\log(g(z))$ if I know $f(z_0)$ for a fixed $z_0$ and if I have a suitable plane cut?

Is it true that we can not care about $\log(g(z))$ because every brunch has the same derivative and we can say that $(\log (g(z))’(a)= \frac {g’(z)}{g(z)}(a)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that for $f(z) = \log(g(z))$ one has
$$
 f'(z) = \frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}
$$
independently of the branch. That reflects the fact that different local branches of the logarithm differ by a constant.

That is not the case for $f(z)=\sqrt [n] {g(z)}$ where different local branches differ by a constant *factor*. Taking the logarithmic derivative of $(f(z))^n = g(z)$ gives
$$
 f'(z) = \frac 1n f(z) \frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}
$$
so that $f'(z)$ depends on the branch chosen for $f(z)$.